# Erlang, io_lib and unicode

Tags: unicode, erlang

I'm having a little trouble getting erlang to give me a unicode string.

Here's what works:

`io:format("~ts~n", [<<226,132,162>>]).

™

ok`

But instead of printing to the console, I want to assign it to a variable.  So I thought:

`T = lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~ts~n", [<<226,132,162>>])).

T.

[8482,10]`

How can I get `T` in the `io_lib` example to contain the `™` symbol so I can write it to a network stream?

Comment: Your binary `<<226,132,162>>` is not a unicode string but a **UTF-8 encoded** unicode string. The list returned from `io_lib:format/2` is a list of unicode code points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of assigning the flattened version to a variable for sending on the network, can you instead re-write your code that sends over the network to accept the binary in the first place and use the formatted write mechanism `~ts` when sending over the socket?

That would also let you avoid the `lists:flatten`, which isn't needed for the built-in IO mechanisms.

Comment: I like it, it's possible, but a much more involved rewrite than I was planning.  Is that the only option?

Comment: I can't say if it is the only option or not; hopefully someone with more experience in Erlang will know if there are options better suited to your case are possible.

Comment: First thing is knowing what you need to do. You can only send bytes over the network, so things like unicode strings, that are composed of codepoints that could be greater than 255 need to be encoded by the sending side and decoded by the receiving side.

UTF-8 is the most used encoding for unicode strings, and that's what you get out of the io_lib call. A very reasonable way to send unicode strings over the network is encoding them in UTF8.

Don't use io_lib:format for that, though. unicode:characters_to_binary/1 is the function meant to transform unicode strings in utf-8 encoded binaries

Comment: @Samuel: That sounds like an _excellent_ answer, you should give it as one so I can give you the +1 :)

Comment: @sarnold Thanks, I added it as an answer for completeness, but there are already two good answers

Answer (score 5):

It does contain the trademark symbol: as you can see [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm), 8482 is its code. It isn't printed as ™ in the shell, because the shell prints as strings only lists which contain printable character code in Latin-1. So `[8482, 10]` *is* a Unicode string (in UTF-32 encoding). If you want to convert it to a different encoding, use the [`unicode`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html) module.

Answer (score 5):

First thing is knowing what you need to do. Then you can adapt your code the best way you find.

Erlang represents unicode strings as lists of codepoints. Unicode codepoints are integers, not bytes. Snce you can only send bytes over the network, things like unicode strings, need to be encoded in byte squences by the sending side and decoded by the receiving side. UTF-8 is the most used encoding for unicode strings, and that's what your binary is, the UTF-8 encoding of the unicode string composed by the codepoint 8482.

What you get out of the `io_lib:format` call is the erlang string representation of that codepoint plus the new line character.

A very reasonable way to send unicode strings over the network is encoding them in UTF-8. Don't use `io_lib:format` for that, though. `unicode:characters_to_binary/1` is the function meant to transform unicode strings in UTF-8 encoded binaries.

In the receiving side (and probably even better in your whole application) you'll have to decide how you will handle the strings, either in encoded binaries (or lists) or in plain unicode lists. But over the network the only choice is using binaries (or iolists wich are possibly deep lists of bytes) and I'll bet the most reasonable encoding for your application will be UTF-8.